# Reading raw audio in iphone SDK

Tags: ios, core-audio, openal

Hi
I want to read and then want to perform some operations on raw audio. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What is the source of the audio? which file type/encoding etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio File Services, Audio Converter Services, and Extended Audio File Services, all in Core Audio.  AV Foundation + Core Media (specifically AVAssetReader) may also be an option, but it's really new, and therefore even less documented and less well understood than Core Audio at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for sample code, "Audio Graph" is a good starting point. The developer has provided a bit of his own documentation, that will help you quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the use for the audio. If latency is an issue, go for audio units. But if is not, a higher layer may be the one you require, such as AudioQueues.